# XMLEvent.writeAsEncodedUnicode

Tags: java, xml, stax, xml-parsing

I've bumped on to an strange issue. I'm trying to use stax to parse and save modified xml file but while everything works in Windows - i get an empty file in Linux. I`ve seen only one post on springfourms about this issue but with no answer. So did anybody had the same problem ?

Sample code below:

```
FileWriter fileWriter = new FileWriter("/home/user/test.xml");

/* SOME CODE */

while (eventReader.hasNext()) {
    XMLEvent event = eventReader.nextEvent();
    switch (event.getEventType()) {
        case XMLEvent.START_ELEMENT: {
            event.asStartElement().writeAsEncodedUnicode(fileWriter);
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you flushed and closed the `FileWriter` afterwards? If not, it could be a buffering issue.

(Personally I'd use an `OutputStreamWriter` wrapped around a `FileOutputStream`, instead of `FileWriter`, as the latter doesn't let you specify the file encoding...)

Comment: No i didn't flush the FileWriter. I'll check Your suggestions as soon as I'll be able to. But still, there should be no difference if the same code works properly in Windows.

Comment: @WitchMan: There could very easily be a difference, based on different buffering at the OS level for example. You shouldn't need to explicitly flush it, but you *should* be closing the writer in a `finally` block.

Comment: @John Skeet: I`ve tryed everything you proposed with no effect :/ So I`ve moved to XMLEventWriter ;)